# Parse iOS SDK Localizing

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform

I am using Parse SDK as a backend and when application loading data from server i see label "Loading". But my app using another language and i wanna translate it. How can i fix it?

Image [here](https://pp.vk.me/c625816/v625816047/ddbd/n-5CGt-celc.jpg)

I am tried to change simulator language and and changing value of Localization native development region key in plist.

Anyone had this problem? I think there is very simple answer, but i cannot find it. :)

Thank you for help!

Comment: one  use Localization/internationalization. ,other solution you should have to keep different images for for each language.

Answer (score 2):

So after a long search, i discovered that you should create a file named **"ParseUI.strings"** in order to change UI elements like *"Loading.."* as you mentioned. You can see the file in the image below. You should use at least [ParseUI framework 1.1.6](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-iOS/releases) for this method.

[image]

After you create a file and named it as "ParseUI.strings" you can change UI elements which parse provides us. You can see which strings are editable [here](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-iOS/blob/master/ParseUI/Resources/Localization/en.lproj/ParseUI.strings).

In your example you want to change "Loading..." string, so all you have to do is enter the code in your **ParseUI.strings** file.

```
"Loading..." = "Whatever thing you want to say...";
```

Thats it, it worked for me.